# ggplot geom_boxplot rendering extremely slowly

Tags: r, ggplot2, x11

I have a data.table with about 90000 rows, let's call it `dtWeights`. I'm trying to plot a boxplot with facets, something along the lines of:

```
ggplot(dtWeights, aes(Day, Weight, group = Day)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ year(Date))
```

Where `dtWeights` is of the form:

```
      Date Day Weight
2005-01-01   1   0.01
2005-01-01   2   0.01
2005-01-01   3   0.01
2005-01-01   4   0.01
2005-01-01   5   0.01
---
2019-01-01  96   0.01
2019-01-01  97   0.01
2019-01-01  98   0.01
2019-01-01  99   0.01
2019-01-01 100   0.01
```

Hence each facet will include 100 boxes (corresponding to `Day`), each representing several hundred `Date`; and there will be about 14 facets in total.

When I plot this in ggplot, and render the plot over X11, the process takes several minutes before the entire image is rendered. If, however, I plot this in base `R`, it renders almost immediately. This could be done with, for example:

```
par(mfrow = c(4, 4))
lapply(
  2005:2019,
  function(localYear){
    boxplot(Weight ~ Day, data = dtWeights[year(Date) == localYear])
  }
)
```

I recognize that base `R` is going to be faster than ggplot, but the speed difference here is far more noticeable than the difference between a simple line chart, or a bar chart.

Can anyone elaborate on why boxplots in ggplot are so painfully slow to render, and explain if there's anything I can do about it on my end?

Comment: I almost always assign the ggplot to an object and then use `ggsave()` to write to a file which is much faster than rendering it inline on the screen. Having ggplots drawn on the screen is just slow and I've never figured out a way around it.

Comment: `ggsave` takes a long time to run as well, and the 7x7 png it produces is 10MB, which seems enormous comparable to other plots of a similar size

Comment: @bk18 Can you include some sample data for others to try? e.g. `set.seed(<some number>)` & generate Weight values randomly (from `runif`, maybe?). I don't use X11, but on my windows machine, generating all the facetted plots for 100k+ rows of similar data in RStudio took around 22 seconds.

Comment: @Z.Lin, that's a similar amount of time it takes on my end. The X11 part is the longest, and I think it's so long because of the size of the file, as I noted in the previous comment. I'm not sure why, but a comparable base R plot is (order of magnitude) 1x10^2 KB, while ggplot is 1x10^4 KB. This makes not only X11 unusable, but the pdf that contains the plot pretty hard to work with.

Comment: I've geom_violin renders much more quickly and has the additional benefit of being able to visualize the shape of the distributions.